# Subsite creation disabled in Central Admin, but users can still create subsites

Tags: permissions, site-collection, central-administration, sub-site

I verified that the settings in Central Admin were disabled so that users could not create their own subsites. However, they are still creating their own subsites. Is there a setting in each site that gives users with Full Control the ability to create subsites which can override Central Admin? When I look at Site and Workspace Creation Permissions for the site collection, only "Manage Hierarchy" is checked. What happens if I uncheck that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two rights that control whether users can create a top-level Web site, subsites, or workspaces: Use Self-Service Site Creation and Create Subsites. See [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288440%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Technet article for details.

Also permissions are defined at the site collection level. For your case you will have to create a new permission level at the site collection where you don't want users to create subsite. See [this](http://hameersaleem.blogspot.ca/2011/03/if-your-users-are-naughty-enough-and.html) blog post for how to do this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I finally had some time to take a look at your suggestions. I'm working in SharePoint 2013, which I failed to mention before. Not sure if that impacts your suggestions, but you gave me a place to start researching. Thank you again.

Comment: No SP 2013 should not make a difference in that process.

Comment: I'm going to consult with our PowerShell guru about running a script that will globally switch that off. We tried adding code to hide the "create subsite" feature, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at your concern, not a exact solution though, The Create subsite will be hidden if you try the below.

go teh site setting then page layouts and template. then select allow creation creation of subsite with this templates only and then select a template which is not used.